# Webpage that gets (some) content from a text file

Tags: html, file, web, lan

I am trying to build a webpage/website on a Windows 7 PC in my local lan that would be getting some info from a text file on the same drive where the website will be hosted (localhost\share\inputfile.txt)

In this file would be info like : Mr Bill Gates and a product that would be ready for him : Samsung LCD TV and also the name of a picture that needs to be shown

In the txt file would be only these three lines :

1: Mr. Bill Gates
2: Samsung LCD TV
3: samsungtv.jpg

The actual webpage should be showing something like :

Welcome "Mr Bill Gates"

Your "Samsung CLD TV"

And the picture "samsungtv.jpg"

The creation of the site, webpage etc is not a problem but the coding of getting data out of a text file is. A nice touch would also be that the site is displaying a slideshow if the text file would be empty. It should of course check every few minutes (5 or so) if there's nothing in the text file, if there is it should refer to a specific page where this info will be used.

Challenged anyone? pleeeeeeeeease :)

Kind regards,
Alain.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer only the pulling out data from a file using client side scripting language**

Fetching data from a file can be accomplished without server side scripting language, but you have to pull and manipulate the data of that file in a way. Here is an example using JavaScript (jQuery):

```
// Make sure the dom is ready
$(function () {
    // Get the contents of the file
    $.get('localhost\share\inputfile.txt', function(data) {
        // If the returned data (as string) is not empty or whitespace
        if (string) {
            // split the string into several strings when a new line occures
            var lines = data.split('\n'); // take note of the \n This is the new line character also known as a line ending, end of line (EOL), or line break.
            // If there are more than 0 lines
            if (lines.length > 0) {
                // For every line console.log out what the line is with the line number prepended.
                for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                    console.log(i + ": " + lines[i]);
                }
            }
        } else {
            // It is empty, do somethin else
            alert('no data present in txt file.');
        }
    });
});
```

Make sure you include a reference to jquery before this JavaScript

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Output:

```
0: Mr. Bill Gates
1: Samsung LCD TV
2: samsungtv.jpg
```

Edit: Here is a complete working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $.get('inputfile.txt', function(data) {
                    //If the returned data is not empty or whitespace
                    if (data) {
                        // split the string into several strings when a new line occures
                        var lines = data.split('\n'); // Take note of the \n This is the new line character also known as a line ending, end of line (EOL), or line break.
                        // If there are more than 0 lines
                        if (lines.length > 0) {
                            // For every line console.log out what the line is with the line number prepended.
                            for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                                console.log(i + ": " + lines[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // It is empty, do somethin else
                        alert('no data present in txt file.');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Make sure that the file `inputfile.txt` is present in the same folder as this document and that the textfile have some lines of text.

Comment: Sorry, java is not usable for me, HTML would work. I dont know the language :(

Comment: This is JavaScript, not Java. To my knowledge there is no way of getting contents of a file using HTML alone. HTML is a markup language, it is designed to structure information on a webpage. HTML can tho embed scripts written in other languages, such as JavaScript, that can manipulate the HTML. It seems to me that you have to learn more about HTML. [here](https://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web) is a good start:

Comment: Will this also work on a local LAN? can I make a "local" copy of the file : http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js ?

Comment: Yes you can copy jquery and run it even offline.

Comment: When I try this in a webpage I only get this output : // Make sure the dom is ready $(function () { // Get the contents of the file $.get('inputfile.txt', function(data) { // If the returned data (as string) is not empty or whitespace if (string) { // split the string into several strings when a new line occures var lines = data.split('\n'); // If there are more than 0 lines if (lines.length > 0) { // For every line console.log out what the line is with the line number prepended. for (var i = 0; i < lines.length;

Comment: Make [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code and i can have a look much easier.

Comment: I think it works now.. but there's no output to the browser?

Comment: Check your console. What browser are you using?

Comment: I tried chrome and explorer. When I look in Chrome it lloks like there a error ( Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined) I would like to show you the page I used, but its to big to paste in this windows :(

Comment: That means jQuery is not present when you are trying to run JavaScript code that depends on it. You will need to add jQuery **before** running the code. Look at my code example in the answer, note the most bottom code i share  `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>` This needs to be added in your HTML document. Please post your code so i can see what you are doing in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) if you have more issues with your code.

Comment: it's online now on : http://1-vaa.us/test.htm basicly it's your code, wit the file inputfile.txt in the same dir. Did I do something wrong? :(

Comment: Look here: http://codeshare.io/V4Ggl You had several errors in you code, the src attribute need to be on a script element. And that script element needs to be added alone. Then you need a new script element that holds the code. It should work now if you have file called `inputfile.txt` in the same folder as the document.

Comment: And just to add. If you want this to function completely offline you will have to download that [jquery-1.11.3.min.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js) file (Just click that link and hit CTRL+S if Chrome) and put it in the same folder as the document and the text file and change the line that says `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>` to this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`

Comment: There was a typo in the variable name. I updated my answer with fully working code. Sorry for the confusion about the typo, that happens some times.

Comment: Did the last copy, it's online now but still not working :( really sorry  :(

Answer (score 0):

For that you need javascript, try this:

```
var xml = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xml.open("GET","PATH HERE",true); 
xml.onreadystatechange = function(){ 
   if(xml.state === 200 && xml.readyState === 4){ 
      var text = xml.response; //this variable will hold the text file content. 
   } 
}
xml.send();
```